# How to update value of an object based on another value inside object literal using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

Currently I have a select option dropdown field. When user selects an option option from the dropdown, index value is returned. Based on the index value, I would like to change the `"Selected"` value from `false` to `true`.

```
var users = [
  {
    "name": "John",
    "selected": false,
    "columns": [
      {
        "index": 0,
        ...
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Sam",
    "selected": false,
    "columns": [
      {
        "index": 1,
        ...
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So let's say if the first option was selected by the user having index value `0`. This should update the first object literal `"Selected"` value to `true`:

```
var users = [
  {
    "name": "John",
    "selected": true,
    "columns": [
      {
        "index": 0,
        ...
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Sam",
    "selected": false,
    "columns": [
      {
        "index": 1,
        ...
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture the [selectedIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex) of the dropdown and the iterate the `users`

Check this example

```
var selectElem = document.getElementById('select');
selectElem.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var index = selectElem.selectedIndex;
  users = users.map( function(user){
     user.selected = user.columns[0].index == index; //this will set the rest of the selected values to false and only selected index to true
     return user;
  }) 
})
```

**Demo**

```js
var users = [
  {
    "name": "John",
    "selected": true,
    "columns": [{ "index": 0 }]
  },
  {
    "name": "Sam",
    "selected": false,
    "columns": [{ "index": 1 }]
  }
];
var selectElem = document.getElementById('select');
selectElem.addEventListener('change', function() {
    var index = selectElem.selectedIndex;
    users = users.map( function(user){
       user.selected = user.columns[0].index == index; 
       return user;
    }); 
    console.log( "updated users ", users );
})
```

```html
<select id="select">
   <option>John</option>
   <option>Sam</option>
</select>
```